# How to correctly deal with rails schema source control branching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, version-control, schema

I have a versionated schema.rb that reflects the master branch migrations.
Whenever I go to another branch and run a new migration in that branch, my database structure is changed.

If I go back to master branch and run db:migrate, that migration changes from the another branch is added to the schema, despite it not belonging to the master branch.

I know this is the way rails works, but how do you devs deal with this?

I heard some people just schema:load to have local database synched with schema, but since it erases all data, it's not a good solution for me because I use a heavy sql dump that helps the development (it is very painful and prone to risks to develop without this data)

Answer (score 2):

Having a `production` dump for development (using the browser/rails server) is great, but you should probably have a `test` environment setup that uses a minimal seeded database.

You can get this by doing `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:schema:load` on an empty (new) DB. 
What I'd normally do is something like:

```
git checkout db/schema.rb
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:reset
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
```

and load fixtures as needed. That will leave you with a schema that should just have your migration changes and a changed timestamp. (Unless you have stuff like setting changes hardcoded into your schema, in which case they'll be lost - we monkeypatched `ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper` to avoid this).

After you've made your migration and done this, commit the `schema.rb` and migration file before you apply the migration to `development`. You can then discard the `schema.rb` with the unwanted changes.

Answer (score 1):

Found this question as I've scoured the web dealing with exactly the same issue - large production dump, different migrations on different branches.

The options seem to be:

1. Meticulously make sure your migrations are reversible and roll them back if needed before switching branches - can be done, but not practical for me as I was given a nasty database and have needed to use raw sql to rework it.
2. Fresh dump from production every time a branch is switched - not practical for local development
3. Generate a new database and seed it with sample data for every git branch - not great for realistic testing in staging

I've been doing #1 for a long time and am looking for a better way.  I've decided to do #2 when needed for staging, since it doesn't get touched too often, and do #3 locally.

The local solution is the interesting part - here's what I have (will edit as I improve on it):

- `database.yml` - we want to work on a different db depending on what git branch we're on (tweaked from another stackoverflow answer I've lost the link to):

```
<%
  branch = `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.strip rescue nil
  use_single_db = !branch || branch == 'master'
  branch_spec = (use_single_db ? "" : "_#{branch}").underscore.gsub(/[\.\/\-]/, '_')
%>

default: &default
  host: '127.0.0.1'
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 10
  port: 3306
  username: 'root'
  password:  'password'
  database: tmp_<%= branch_spec %>

development:
  <<: *default
```

- This does mean, every time we create a new branch, we'll have to create a database and seed it.  You'll need to populate `seeds.rb` for your use case - tedious, but necessary.  (You mentioned that there's quite a bit of data you need for development - you can run all sorts of ruby in this file, perhaps you load the big stuff you need from a csv or something?)  One thing I make sure to do in `seeds.rb` is to populate the
  `schema_migrations` table with the current migrations on the branch
  (and any other appropriate edits to `seeds.rb`) for when that is mysteriously NOT loaded from structure.sql.  More on that at the
  end.

```
conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
schema_migrations_versions = [
  ...
  20160407183816,
  20220317151510,
  20220414173833,
  20220425184402,
  20220711221447,
  20220712172621,
]
if conn.execute("SELECT * FROM schema_migrations").to_a.length == 0
  conn.execute("INSERT INTO schema_migrations (version) VALUES (#{schema_migrations_versions.join('),(')})")
end
```

- To actually do the creation/seeding, run the following (I made a bash script so that this is a quick, one-time command):

```
bin/rails db:create
bin/rails db:structure:load # you might need db:schema:load if you're using schema.rb
bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=development
mv db/migrate db/migrate_x
bin/rails db:seed
mv db/migrate_x db/migrate
```

Why the hacky `mv` command you ask?  We have a chicken-and-egg problem:

- The `schema.rb` or `structure.sql` file is the 'source of truth' for the database structure at any given time - presumably, any migrations you have committed to the repo have been run on the database and this file has been updated with them.  When you run `db:structure:load`, it creates all your tables as if all the migrations have been run.
- Great, let's seed the database.  But then Rails complains that you haven't run your migrations on it yet, because the `schema_migrations` table is empty, because we haven't seeded the database yet.  This is supposed to get added from structure.sql but I find that most of the time (all the time?) it doesn't actually get added, and I haven't been able to figure out why.
- Ok, so run migrations first.  But unless you carefully create your migrations to check whether they should be run ("create if not exists" type stuff), your migrations will fail because that table exists, that column exists, or doesn't exist... can't do it.

It is possible to set a rails setting to just not check for migrations, but it seems equally annoying to temporarily edit the config just to seed the database, so I have opted for moving the migrations somewhere rails can't find them for the duration of the seeding.

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like a git problem than a Rails one. Git allows for branch changes with new files, since they would cause no conflict with the master branch, or whatever branch you're checking out. In Rails, creating a migration creates a new untracked file in the db/migrations directory. Since it is a new file, you are able to checkout the master branch with no issue.

```
~/code/node/server (test)
$ git checkout -b dev
Switched to a new branch 'dev'

~/code/node/server (dev)
$ touch test.txt

~/code/node/server (dev)
$ git checkout test
Switched to branch 'test'

~/code/node/server (test)
$ git status
On branch test
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        test.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

In this example, I start on branch 'test' and then checkout a new branch called 'dev'. I then create a test file and make sure not to start tracking it. Then checkout the 'test' branch again. (Notice no issue here). `git status` reveals that the untracked file followed me back to the 'test' branch.

If you want the migration file to stay local to the non-master branch where it was created, you can do a few things:

1. You can stage and commit this file to the non-master branch. After you do this, the file will reside on that branch and not follow you back to the master branch (or whatever other branch you decide to checkout).
2. You can stage this file, and then stash it:

   - `git add path_to/your_file`
   - `git stash`
   - to retrieve the stash later you can `git stash pop`
   - for more info on git stash, read [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)
3. Delete the file.

If you do accidentally migrate on a branch you didn't mean to, you can always rollback the migration using `bundle exec rake db:rollback` until you get to the desired schema state.

Hopefully this helps, and happy coding!

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the response! I may have been misunderstood. I meant that branches that have different migrations (and therefore different schemas) force us to schema:load to keep the fisical db structure matching to the current branch schema in dev. It is not helpful when we need to work with a large production dump because we'd have to restore again after schema:load. Maybe the approach to develop using a dump is not the better choice, but I wonder if there's a way to keep working this way